# Bootstrap Multiselect support for bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5, bootstrap-multiselect

I am trying to use Bootstrap-multiselect. But, what I am getting on web, all is for bootstrap 4. Is there any version to support bootstrap 5?

Answer (score 2):

The multiple attribute is also supported

More info [enter link description here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/select/)

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select class="form-select" multiple aria-label="multiple select example">
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Actually, I am asking for a plugin named bootstrap-multiselect.

Comment: There is small discussion on this topic under the same repo.    
Check this out, may be you can get some help [link](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/discussions/1202)